# Removing jQuery but .className += not working?

Tags: javascript

I had a very simple off canvas menu working fine in jQuery. Im attempting to rewrite it in vanilla javascript.

In the following code addClass (which is jQuery) is working, but .className += is not.

```
var burger = document.getElementsByClassName('l-burger');
var html = document.querySelectorAll('html');

$(burger).click(function(){
  $(html).className += ' menu-opening'; // not working 

  setTimeout(function(){
    $(html).addClass('menu-open');
    $(html).removeClass('menu-opening');
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: *"Im attempting to rewrite it in vanilla javascript"* 1. You mean using the DOM directly (jQuery *is* "vanilla JavaScript"). 2. Then why are you still using jQuery? `$(html)` is calling jQuery and getting back a jQuery object.

Comment: **1.** You mentioned that you're going to replace jQuery, yet you're using `$(html)`. **2.** There should be only one `<html>` element per document, there is no need to use `querySelectorAll`, use `document.documentElement` instead. **3.** Once you get ahold of a reference to the native element, you better use `classList.add('someClassName')`

Comment: ...although `className += " menu-opening"` will work too if you don't want to use `classList`. but `classList`'s support is very good these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because $(html) gives you a jQuery object, not a native DOMElement.

You can access the native element at the key `0` of the jQuery object:

```
$(html)     // returns a jQuery object
$(html)[0]  // returns a native DOMElement
```

So to add a classname, you should use something like this:

```
$(html).className += ' menu-opening';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `document.querySelector('html').className = document.querySelector('html').className + ' myClassName'`

Or as suggested in the comments:

```
var htmlNode = document.querySelector('html');
htmlNode.className = htmlNode.className + ' myClassName'
```

Or even cleaner: `document.querySelector('html').classList.add('myClassname')`

Comment: It would be a lot more efficient to save a reference to the element in a variable, instead of querying the DOM twice.